# SSO Integration Using SAML 2.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am working on integrating our application with client's Identity management system using SAML 2.0. Below is the requirement

1. The login screen of our application will have an option for Single Sign On. when clicked user will be directed to the login screen of Identity management system
2. The Identity provider will validate user's credentials and send us the information back to our application
3. based on the input from Identity provider the application has to be provide access to the user.

Now, the client has asked us to provide them SAML meta data files. Our application is developed in dot net.

I had a look at component space and ATC Inc components that can be used for SAML generation however I need help to start this.

Can someone help me on this? This is something new which I haven't worked.

Thanks,
Abhilash

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simpler integration than coding support directly into your application, check out the PingOne Application Provider Service (APS) "SAML as a Service" from Ping Identity. A handful of lines of .NET code (or Java or Ruby or Perl, etc) to integrate via a RESTful API and you're done. No need to embed complicated SAML SP code and the security overhead that comes with it [Disclaimer: I do work for Ping].

HTH
Ian

Comment: Thank you for responding but we are looking for using .net components ....Can someone help me on this??? Thanks in advance.